# Perform some calculations using django form. Which framework?

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-forms

I have an input form with couple of input fields mostly numerical. I have a python script which takes the input values then performs some medium calculations (arrays, loops, etc) and gives results.

I would like to display results without a page refresh below the input form. Simplest example would be to display an average from the three input fields below when user clicks calculate button or instantly without even clicking.

Could anybody point me to the right direction how this would be implemented? I don't know what's the best framework to use for this. Just Ajax or Angular? Perform calls on client side or server?

Comment: I  think you should checkout jquery library becuase it's a small task.

Comment: You should use [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). `Angular` is front-end framework. What you require is a to send a `request` from the client side to your server. This `request` asks you to perform some numerical task. You then respond to this `request` from your server and send a `response`. The `response` is then handled by your client-side `AJAX` function